# Name for mapping from function to scalar

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, terminology

Is there a special name for a mapping from functions to scalars such as for example $(\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I think this is called a "functional". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)

Comment: @mr_e_man 5 people thought that comment was worth upvoting, so I think it should be converted to an answer. Since you got here first, could you do it?

Comment: @Museful do you mind indicating in which context this appeared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In broad generality, there is, to the best of my knowledge, no special term for this kind of function.  However, in some contexts, we can say more.  For example, if $V$ is a vector space, then a (linear) function
$$ f : V \to \mathbb{R}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
f : V \to \mathbb{C} $$
is called a (*linear*) *functional*.  Note that the codomain needn't be the base field of $V$.  This is relevant to the current question, as certain classes of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself form vector spaces which are of interest in a branch of mathematics called "[functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis)".

If $u$ and $v$ are two functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, then we may define scalar multiplication and addition of functions by pointwise evaluation.  That is, if $u, v : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, then define
$$ u + v : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} : x\mapsto u(x) + v(x)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\alpha u : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \alpha u(x). $$
Under these operations, the set of function from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself forms a vector space, so define
$$ V := \{ u \mid u : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} \}. $$
A function $f : V \to \mathbb{R}$ is then a *functional*.

Personally, I would find this usage a *little* awkward, as I usually consider function spaces with a little more structure (e.g. replace general functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with smooth functions, or functions which are integrable), and I usually consider only linear functionals, but I don't think that anyone would be confused if you referred to functions of the form
$$ f : (\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R} $$
as *functionals*.